# SELECT or Filter from JSON(?) Array

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I have a call to a large JSON data set. It has multiple items and each item has multiple pieces of information. I want to output only one item's single piece of information. So I need to filter down the information to only one item or use a SELECT statement such as you might in SQL. I tried the following, but I receive this error: `error: TypeError: Cannot find function filter in object [object Object]. (line 28, file "gwspidy api")`. I can't for the life of me figure out how to boil the data down to just that one item. It is hard to test this code in the google apps scripting.

```
function test3(itemID) {
  var myUrl = "http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/all-items/all";
  var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myUrl);
  var jsonString = jsonData.getContentText();
  var jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonString).result;
  var jsonFilter = jsonArray.filter(function(itemID,jsonArray){if(jsonArray.data_id.match(itemID)) {return itemID;}});
  var adjustedValue = (jsonFilter.min_sale_unit_price / 100);
  return adjustedValue;  
}
```

Also, a secondary question regards the cache service. I asked a previous question, and I was directed towards using the cache service. Unfortunately that has a data size limit. How might I go about saving the Array with only the data_id and the min_sale_unit_price to lower the size of the data set.

Thanks ahead of time for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good option would be to use [ScriptDb Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script-db/), but if the amount of data is great, you'll run faster with the problems of the limits of the quotas of service.

From your example, the following works:

```
var json = JSON.parse('{"result": [{"id": 1, "value": "value1"}, {"id": 2, "value": "value2"}]}').result;

var items = json.filter(function(item) {
  if(item.id === 2) {
    return item;
  }
});

Logger.log(items);
```

Comment: The data call is probably about 20,000 items each with like 15 pieces. So you are saying that in this instance, it would actually be better to use the ScriptDb Services?

And I had tried something similar to that ( `var jsonFilter = jsonArray.filter(function(item,itemID){if(item.data_id === itemID ) {return item}});` ) and I keep getting an error: `TypeError: Cannot call method "filter" of undefined. (line 27, file "gwspidy api")`. I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: For the amount of data handled certain problems will arise given the size limits (quotas) imposed by the service.

Is it possible to post a sample of the resulting JSON?

Comment: All the data comes from here: `http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/all-items/all`. I don't know how I would be able to show you the parsed text mostly because I don't even know how I might be able to see it myself. It makes testing difficult to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Change line:

```
var jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonString).result;
```

by:

```
var jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonString).results;
```

Comment: Ah, great, thanks. Now I am getting an `overflow` error though.